# why multithread mysql query with python cost so much time

Tags: python, mysql, python-multithreading

there is a sql, query time is 3s. I think that if I create 3 threads, each thread run this sql at almost the same time, the whole time should be almost 3s.  but actually it takes 8s. why?

the code like this:

```py
import pymysql
import threading
import time
from config.db import db_config

def get_connection():
    return pymysql.connect(**db_config)

def test(sql):
    print('start query...')
    st = time.time()
    conn = get_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    print('end query.. timeuse: ', time.time() - st)

def get_threads(num=3):
    threads = []
    for i in range(num):
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=test, args=(sql,)))
    return threads

sql = "a sql cost 3s"

def main(num):
    threads = get_threads(num)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

the running result:

```
>>> main(1)
start query...
end query.. timeuse:  3.0793652534484863

>>> main(3)
start query...
start query...
start query...
end query.. timeuse:  7.348235368728638
end query.. timeuse:  7.411351919174194
end query.. timeuse:  8.129048585891724
```

remarks: the mysql engine is innodb, max_connections is 12384

Comment: The server needs longer to process 3 queries at the same time?

Comment: of course, but the 3 query should be triggered at almost the same time, so the cost time almost the same as 1 query is expected.

Comment: Did you verify that?

Comment: no, I didn't. It's just my thought. I wanna know where is wrong.

Comment: We can't verify your assumptions. You did not even include the query in the question. You will have to test that yourself.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a threading issue. Rather, it's caused by trying to create 3 connections at the same time. The db server or the client may be struggling to handle 3 connection requests simultaneously. Try:

`def test(sql):
    print('start query...')
    conn = get_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    st = time.time()
    cur.execute(sql)
    print('end query.. timeuse: ', time.time() - st)
` 

instead to see whether it is the connection or the query that is slowing things down.

Comment: thanks, i did as you said, mark the time cost of connection and query. but it turned out that the connection cost less than 0.004s.